# Vacation Days of Assistant Professor in Canada

Tags: university, working-time, assistant-professor

I may apply for an Assistant Professor (AP) position at York University in Toronto, Canada. Since I live in Europe, I would like to know how many vacation days are available in this position. For example, what does an AP do in those weeks where no classes take place? Does the AP have to go to the office or can he stay home? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The answer to question depends upon the specific university you would be working at. A 9-month contract might not have any vacation (you are expected to be working when school is in session). A 12-month contract might come with vacation. However, the specific answer to your question depends upon which school you applied to.

Comment: Is the 9 month contract a thing in Canada as well? I have a faint impression that TT positions are 'full time' here. However that doesn't change the fact that this question is specific to the university and better asked directly.

Comment: The York university, as most (but not all) Canadian universities is unionized.
 Here is their webpage with the info: [https://www.yufa.ca/](https://www.yufa.ca/). If you look at the agreement you can see that there is one month of paid vacation (over 12 months, I don't know any Canadian university with 9 months contracts). In general you can do what you want during that time, but the North American system expects you to take care of your students even during that time (depending of the field, disappearing for a month can be detrimental to your lab!).

Comment: @Zenon indeed, disappearing for a month can be detrimental, but nothing prevent you from cutting these vacations into smaller block.

Answer (score 4):

How much vacation time an assistant professor gets is answered by the collective agreement in force at York U. According to a comment above, that's 4 weeks. These are days when you can do whatever you please.
Obviously, there are constraints regarding the time when you can take this vacation, as pointed out by some comments.

More importantly your question suggests that there's potentially vacation whenever there are no classes. So for one thing you may need the time between semesters to develop your teaching material, but also an Assistant Professor is not a teaching-only position, it's research/supervision + teaching + typically some admin duties.

Finally, note that in many Canadian Universities there is a summer term with classes going on between may and August. So you could very well end up teaching all year around; there's typically about 3 to 4 weeks between the end of classes for one term and the beginning of the next (and that time includes exams and marking).

Comment: That's a very good answer. Thank you very much!